# how to show the currently shown entries range in angular

Tags: angularjs, pagination

This is what I have used to achieve pagination:

```
<pagination total-items="reportCount" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" page="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" ng-model="currentPage"></pagination>
```

How do I get it show the range of entries currently shown.. like.. `1-10 of 46 entries`. `11-20 of 46` and so on..

I am able to get it using the value of `currentPage` and `itemsPerPage` by doing as follows:

```
<span id="page_info">Showing {{(currentPage-1) * itemsPerPage + 1}} - {{currentPage * itemsPerPage}} of {{reportCount}} entries</span>
```

But the issue is in the last page, where the last record is not just `currentPage * itemsPerPage`, like.. it shows `41-50 of 46 entries`.

It should work with `{{Math.min((currentPage * itemsPerPage), reportCount)`}} but for some reason it isn't evaluating it here.

Any ideas how to get this fixed? or any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser Object Model(`BOM`) will not be directly available when angular bindings are evaluated like `Math`, `console`, `location`, `window`, etc. You can call them inside a function but not directly on inside binding (Thought there are ways to do that by keep that `BOM` property on `$scope`, I'd not recommend to do that). To make it working create a javascript function for inside a `$scope` and call it on binding level.

```
<span id="page_info">
  Showing {{(currentPage-1) * itemsPerPage + 1}} - {{endCount(currentPage,itemsPerPage, reportCount)}} of {{reportCount}} entries
</span>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.endCount = function (currentPage, itemsPerPage, reportCount) {
   return Math.min((currentPage * itemsPerPage), reportCount);
}
```

Comment: This worked as you said Pankaj. So there's no way to get this done directly inside the view, is there? just how we evaluate expressions inside the `{{ }}`, we can't do things like these then?

Comment: There is a way, as I said in my answer. For that you have to do `$scope.Math = Math` in order to make it working on UI. I wouldn't recommend to go for it, since it expose BOM props on binding and doesn't looks clean.

Comment: @Rai Glad to know it helped :)